# I am looking for a good load balancing (or reverse proxy) software for TCP and HTTP, any suggestions?

Tags: http, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, tcp

I am looking for a good load balancing (or reverse proxy) software for TCP and HTTP, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For HTTP, look at [Nginx](http://nginx.org/), [Varnish](http://varnish-cache.org/), or [Pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound/). For general TCP software load balancing, look at [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) and [Balance](http://www.inlab.de/balance.html).

Answer (score 0):

HaProxy might be of use to you. 
http://haproxy.1wt.eu/

Answer (score 0):

[nginx](http://nginx.org/) works quite well as a caching reverse proxy and can be configured in a load balance/fail-over setup.  Perhaps if you can describe the application we can provide you more specific recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

If it's even remotely possible I'd recommend using round-robin DNS.

- its cheap (free)
- easy to configure/manage
- pushes fail-over functionality to the client allowing multi-site failover without split-brain issues
- it doesn't break
- session affinity is implicit (even for stateless HTTP)

C.

Answer (score 0):

haproxy is the best loadbalancing software I came across, I can highly recommend it, even for high traffic (>100mbit/s) websites.
Pound sucks performance-wise and does not have a lot of basic features.