# I am looking for a good load balancing (or reverse proxy) software for TCP and HTTP, any suggestions?

Tags: http, tcp, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I am looking for a good load balancing (or reverse proxy) software for TCP and HTTP, any suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/164680/i-am-looking-for-a-good-load-balancing-or-reverse-proxy-software-for-tcp-and-h)

I am looking for a good load balancing (or reverse proxy) software for TCP and HTTP, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't beat [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) for simplicity and speed. If you need caching try adding [varnish](http://varnish-cache.org/) into the mix.

Answer (score 0):

[squid](http://www.thefraggle.com/2007/04/09/http-load-balancing-with-squid/) is an excellent reverse proxy -- mostly used for caching, but, as the article I pointed to explains, also good for load balancing.  However, serverfault.com is likely to give you better answers on this question of yours, since it has nothing to do with programming!